# If C++ can reorder memory reads & writes, then why it does not reorder lock_guard?

Tags: c++

Just curious. Subj. How C++ compiler knows not to reorder lock_guard in the beginning of the block? How C++ standard regulates it? Thanks.

```
{
    lock_guard<mutex> g(m);  // why this is not reordered to after "a = b"?
    a = b;
}
```

Comment: *"Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated"* and reordering these expressions would also break the "as if" rule, so no, the compiler shall not reorder these statements.

Comment: memory barriers. next

Comment: In short: the compiler is a C++ compiler because it implements the C++ rules. And those rules tell the compiler how your code should be compiled.